# LSTM for predicting multiple sequences at the same time

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm, sequence, recurrent-neural-network

I'm currently working on a project regarding a dataset that contains smartphone usage data from roundabout 200 users over a period of 4 months. For each user, I have a dataframe consisting of app-log events (Name of the App, Time, Location etc.). My goal is to predict the dwell time for the next app a user is going to open. I don't want to build one model for each user, but instead, I'm trying to build a model for all combined users. Now I'm struggling with finding an architecture that is suitable for this project.

The records are not evenly spaced in time, and the length of each dataframe differs. I want to utilize the temporal dependencies while simultaneously learn from multiple users at once, thus my input would be multiple parallel sequences of app usage durations with additional features and my output again multiple parallel sequences containing the dwell-time for the next app, but as the sequences are not evenly spaced in time nor have the same length it seems not suitable. I just wanted to get some ideas on how to structure the data properly and what you think would be a suitable approach. I would really appreciate some ideas or reading recommendations.

Comment: its seems all the user information could be put into one dataframe and the dataframe could be ingested by the model as a batch

Comment: That's an idea that was not in my mind until now, have you ever done sth similar or could you recommend some readings about it?

Comment: I have done multi feature input for an lstm model